# It's possible to append Cursors?

Tags: android, android-cursor

I'm looking to add the **content** of an `Cursor` to an existing `Cursor`.

Comment: yes. use a MergeCursor.

Comment: OR... you can use the `UNION` clause in your queries, to get an already "merged" cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes as @njzk2 already suggested you can use a `MergeCursor` like this:

```
final Cursor mergedCursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[] {
        firstCursor,
        secondCursor
});
```

After that you can use the merged `Cursor` like you would use any other. `getColumn()` and `getColumnIndex` will return the values of the item at the current position. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html) you can find some documentation.

Of course you can always `JOIN` tables or use `UNION` in your SQL queries.